# I need to turn a .json into an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building an app which manages timetables for my school with unity. I would like to work with a huge json file we have. I think turning it into an array would be easiest

Apologies for the bloat, although this is only ~1% of what we have.

```
[
  {
    "DayNumber": "2",
    "Period": "4",
    "ClassCode": "9HM.A2",
    "TeacherCode": "YOUB",
    "RoomCode" : "205",
    "ClassTime" : "12:40"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "3",
    "Period": "2",
    "ClassCode": "9HM.A2",
    "TeacherCode": "YOUB",
    "RoomCode" : "205",
    "ClassTime" : "10:00"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "5",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9HM.A2",
    "TeacherCode": "YOUB",
    "RoomCode" : "205",
    "ClassTime" : "11:08"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "8",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9HM.A2",
    "TeacherCode": "YOUB",
    "RoomCode" : "205",
    "ClassTime" : "11:20"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "10",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9HM.A2",
    "TeacherCode": "YOUB",
    "RoomCode": "205",
    "ClassTime": "11:08"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "1",
    "Period": "6",
    "ClassCode": "9IST.B1",
    "TeacherCode": "FRWK",
    "RoomCode" : "166",
    "ClassTime" : "14:27"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "4",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9IST.B1",
    "TeacherCode": "FRWK",
    "RoomCode" : "166",
    "ClassTime" : "11:40"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "5",
    "Period": "6",
    "ClassCode": "9IST.B1",
    "TeacherCode": "FRWK",
    "RoomCode" : "166",
    "ClassTime" : "14:27"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "6",
    "Period": "6",
    "ClassCode": "9IST.B1",
    "TeacherCode": "FRWK",
    "RoomCode" : "166",
    "ClassTime" : "14:27"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "9",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9IST.B1",
    "TeacherCode": "FRWK",
    "RoomCode" : "166",
    "ClassTime" : "11:40"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "2",
    "Period": "5",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "14:20"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "3",
    "Period": "3",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "11:20"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "4",
    "Period": "2",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "10:00"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "5",
    "Period": "4",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "12:01"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "7",
    "Period": "5",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "14:20"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "8",
    "Period": "2",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "10:00"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "9",
    "Period": "2",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "10:00"
  },
  {
    "DayNumber": "10",
    "Period": "4",
    "ClassCode": "9SC.5",
    "TeacherCode": "TRUC",
    "RoomCode" : "27",
    "ClassTime" : "12:01"
  }
]
```

I would like to turn it into this automatically, or even figure out how i can process the above file in c#

```
string[][] _9HM_A2 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"2", "4", "9HM.A2", "YOUB", "205", "12:40"},
    new string[] {"3", "2", "9HM.A2", "YOUB", "205", "10:00"},
    new string[] {"5", "3", "9HM.A2", "YOUB", "205", "11:08"},
    new string[] {"8", "3", "9HM.A2", "YOUB", "205", "11:20"},
    new string[] {"10", "3", "9HM.A2", "YOUB", "205", "11:08"},
};
    string[][] _9IST_B1 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "1", "6", "9IST.B1", "FRWK", "166", "14:27"},
    new string[] {"4", "3", "9IST.B1", "FRWK", "166", "11:40"},
    new string[] {"5", "6", "9IST.B1", "FRWK", "166", "14:27"},
    new string[] {"6", "6", "9IST.B1", "FRWK", "166", "14:27"},
    new string[] {"9", "3", "9IST.B1", "FRWK", "166", "11:40"},
};
    string[][] _9SC_5 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "2", "5", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "14:20"},
    new string[] { "3", "3", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "11:20"},
    new string[] { "4", "2", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "10:00"},
    new string[] { "5", "4", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "12:01"},
    new string[] { "7", "5", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "14:20"},
    new string[] { "8", "2", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "10:00"},
    new string[] { "9", "2", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "10:00"},
    new string[] { "10", "4", "9SC.5", "TRUC", "27", "12:01"},
};
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json. It's a pretty standard tool for dealing with JSON.

Comment: Curiosity question: why are you using Unity for this?

Comment: As i am good at c# and it is going to be an app to auto notify before periods. I understand i should not use unity but it seems to be the easiest option for me. I am open to suggestions

Comment: If you are good at C# then you shouldn't be using Unity and you would know this.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Unity and JSON.Net historically haven't mixed well together.

Comment: You have plenty of other options while still using C#, to be honest: A console application, a WinForms application, a WPF application, a UWP application, a WebForms application or an ASP.NET MVC web application (if you want it to be browser-based). Though this doesn't answer your current question of course :)

Comment: The native unity JSON library cannot deal with a JSON list.

Comment: @DavidG Could you elaborate? Never used Unity before.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a huge json file, then maybe instead of an array you should consider using an liteweight database. If you needed to do aggregation on the data, the database might be a better fit. Loading a huge json file into an array might eat up your memory resources. But if you still want to try an array, why not use a dictionary of lists.

My assumptions based on your example json is that the structure of that json won't change so you can map a c# POCO class to that data.

```
public class ClassSched
    {
        public string DayNumber { get; set; }
        public string Period { get; set; }
        public string ClassCode { get; set; }
        public string TeacherCode { get; set; }
        public string RoomCode { get; set; }
        public string ClassTime { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is a snippet of how i might want to store this data.

```
Dictionary<string, List<ClassSched>> dictClassSched = new Dictionary<string, List<ClassSched>>();

/*
    * Here you open up your Json file and read it,
    * then you loop over the rows
    * and grab the class Code and assign it to classCode variable
    * and assign the row of the json into the jsonRow variable.
    * 
    */

var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassSched>(jsonrow.ToString());
if ( dictClassSched.TryGetValue(classCode, out List<ClassSched> scheds))
{
    scheds.Add(c);
    dictClassSched[classCode] = scheds;
}
else
{
    dictClassSched.Add(classCode, new List<ClassSched>() { c });
}
```

So above we Deserialize a json row into a POCO. then we take the classCode and look it up in the dictionary, if we find a hit, then the scheds variable is populated with the contents. We then insert the new row, then set the list back to the dictionary. If we don't find an entry for that classcode then we create a new List and assign classSched instance to it.

-HTH